# Multipart POST request in Python

Tags: python-3.x, curl, post, request, python-requests

I have the following curl command which works perfectly in Terminal

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://online.tet_url' --form license='test_licence' --form product='pdfserver' --form readUSdates='true' --form pdf-filename='@/dir/test.pdf'
```

Please note that pdf-filename refers to location of a pdf file on my local machine.
When I try to use python request package like:

```
url = "https://online.tet_url"
payload = {"license": 'test_licence',
'product': 'pdfserver',
'readUSdates': 'true',
'pdf-filename': '@/dir/test.pd'}
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
}
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload)
```

I recieve 400 error with the following message:

++++++

Apache Tomcat/8.0.32 - Error reportH1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}.line {height: 1px; background-color: #525D76; border: none;}

## HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type

**type** Status report

**message** Unsupported Media Type

**description** The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.

#### Apache Tomcat/8.0.32

++++++++

Please note that I have tried to import it to Postman and when I ran it from there it didn’t work.
I have tried converting it to python request using  https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html and it didn’t work again.

I appreciate if you help me to post this curl using Python.

Answer (score 0):

For uploading documents we should use a separate package

```
from pathlib import Path

url = 'https://online.tet_url'
data = {
        'license': 'test_licence',
        'product': 'pdfserver',
        'readUSdates': 'true }
files = {
        'pdf-filename': Path(directory).open('rb'),
        }
response = requests.request('POST', url, data=data, files=files)
```